# Google Re-marketing Dynamic Variables

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I have a page, on which i generate new elements and data with AJAX. The problem that re-marketing code fires only on page load... I want to it to fire it later when data is generated with AJAX and send that data in google_custom_params.

I tried it by the help of Google Tag Manager, but its not working as it should.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

In Google Tag Manager you can create Tags with Firing Rules that listen for events other than the page has loaded.

For example you could create a Tag which fires when `{{event}} equals foo` then when you AJAX page has loaded, execute a `dataLayer.push({"event":"foo", ... })`, which calls the Tag.

A simple way of testing it is to create a Tag which contains custom html that outputs a `console.log`
eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('omg it works');
</script>
```